# Загрузка определенного контента

Tags: jquery, ajax

```html
<div id="preload" class="preload"></div>
<div id="content">
    <a href="#" id="/ajax.html" onclick="link();">Test</a>
</div>
```

```js
function link() {
    $("#preload").html('Загружаем...');
    var url = $("a").attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#content").html(html);
            $("div.preload").remove();
        }
    });
}
```

При клике подгружается содержимое
<sub>[ajax.html](http://nowhere)</sub>

```html
<div id="12345">...</div>
```

Соответственно загружается весь файл, а необходимо загрузить только контент с идентификатором 12345. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут даже форма ajax не нужна

[jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load)

```html
<div id='content'>
    <a href="#" onclick='$("#content").load("ajax.html #12346");'>Load</a>
</div>
```

<sub>[ajax.html](http://nowhere)</sub>

```html
<div id="12345">qeqqe</div>
<div id="12346">qwert</div>
```